# Spring data jpa PostgreSql: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone >= bytea

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Use Spring Boot 2.6.6, Spring data JPA, Hibernate 5.6.7.Final, PostgreSql Driver 42.3.3, PostgreSql Server 14.

I have query:
`SELECT u.* FROM "user" u WHERE ((:createdAtFrom = NULL OR :createdAtTo = NULL) OR (u.birthday BETWEEN :createdAtFrom AND :createdAtTo))`.

But it not working.

I got error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone >= bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I turned on hibernate debug for sql parameters and see next rows:

```
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARBINARY] - [null]
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARBINARY] - [null]
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARBINARY] - [null]
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [VARBINARY] - [null]
```

Why `VARBINARY`?
I tried `java.util.Date`, `java.time.LocalDateTime` - same error. what wrong?

There is demo repo: https://gitlab.com/Tsyklop/jpa-test/-/tree/master

Comment: I tried one thing. And if pass `null` [there](https://gitlab.com/Tsyklop/jpa-test/-/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/jpatest/service/UserManageServiceImpl.java#L33) I got error.

Is there any workarounds? I want search all rows without timestamp filter or with timestamp filter.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement seems to be missing a `CAST` so that Postgresql knows that the bind parameters are of the type of the columns they get compared to.

Also comparisons with `NULL` should always be made with `IS NULL`. See [Why doesn't SQL support "= null" instead of "is null"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078837/why-doesnt-sql-support-null-instead-of-is-null)

So something like

```
SELECT u.* FROM "user" u 
WHERE ((:createdAtFrom IS NULL OR :createdAtTo IS NULL) 
OR (u.birthday BETWEEN 
    CAST (:createdAtFrom TO TIMESTAMP) 
    AND CAST (:createdAtTo TO TIMESTAMP))
)
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Read this post: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2491#issuecomment-1102348149

Comment: IDK if this depends on the Postgresql version 
but you might use this expression:
`CAST (:createdAtFrom AS TIMESTAMP)` (AS instead of TO)