# Getting root parent

Tags: mysql, hierarchical

```
+--------+---------+-----------+
|   id   | title   | parent_id |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|    1   | Lvl-1   |   null    |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|    2   | Lvl-2   |   null    |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|    3   | Lvl-11  |     1     |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|    4   | Lvl-12  |     1     |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|    5   | Lvl-121 |     4     |
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

How do i actualy get root parent for each row
For example, row with `id 5` have parent with `id 4` and `id 4` have parent with `id 1`, so root id for `id 5` is `id 1`
I dont have any idea on how to do it and is there a way to solve this by using only 1 query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You are simply not going to believe this

[I wrote a post in the DBA StackExchange (October 24, 2011) on how to pull this off using Stored Procedure programming. I also included some sample data and the results](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7161/877).

Comment: As per his question : "I dont have any idea on how to do it and is there a way to solve this by using only 1 query" as opposed the the procedural loop/concatonate you have here.  Solution still works, I'd be curious if there was a 'one select statement' solution

Comment: SQL Server has the power to perform recursive queries with a single statement. MySQL does not. That's why it is write as proceduual.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA so basically stored procedure is the only way? i bet this can be done with trigger too.But is it achiveable wit pure query only?

Comment: No pure SQL way is possible without making some assumptions. For example, if you knew the maximum length of all paths for any id was 7, you could probably write an elaborate LEFT JOIN query of the table against itself 6 times. Once you get the right SQL for ids whose length was less than or equal to 7, what if an id now had a length of 8 or more? The query would have to be dynamically altered to accommodate longer hierarchies. Again, the idea is making that assumption in the design of the query. The stored procedure makes no assumptions. It simply performs preorder tree traversal.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA haiz, thats why mysql need to implement some sort recursive fucntion like other rdbms do

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short query doing what you're asking, assuming your table is called `foo` and that you want to know the root of `<id>`:

```
SELECT f.id, f.title
FROM (
    SELECT @id AS _id, (SELECT @id := parent_id FROM foo WHERE id = _id)
    FROM (SELECT @id := <id>) tmp1
    JOIN foo ON @id IS NOT NULL
    ) tmp2
JOIN foo f ON tmp2._id = f.id
WHERE f.parent_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tree structure is more than say two layers deep you're searching for [modified preorder tree traversal](http://imrannazar.com/Modified-Preorder-Tree-Traversal)

Comment: modified preorder tree traversal is hard to maintain

Comment: a stored procedure is expensive to query. it depends on your use case  what makes the most sense.