# Child grandparent relationship either in SQL or Qlik Sense

Tags: mysql, sql, qlikview, qliksense

I have only one table

[image]

from the above table I need to find out the grandparent of child_ID.

The output must be like below

[image]

Please let me know the code either in SQL or in Qlik Sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: It's not clear to me that child_id d has a grandparent of a? I guess this should only be the case for child_id c. Or am I'm missing something?

Comment: how come child_id b's parent_id and grandparent_id is 'a'? How can they both be same?

Comment: The expected output is not the grandparent id, but to list the ultimate parent (root) for each child. Also, there is no question in your post, only a code request.

Comment: @shadow i think this is the question "I need to find out the grandparent of child_ID." which is there in the post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting root parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480095/getting-root-parent)

Comment: @India.Rocket that's not a question. That's a statement of a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

From you example it's hard to judge what you actually want to do, but I am assuming you are trying to create a Hierarchy.

In Qlik, what you are looking for is called [Hierarchy](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/DataSource/Hierarchies.htm)

For your example, see below script:

```
Data:
LOAD * INLINE [
    Parent_ID, Child_ID
    a, b
    b, c
    c, d
    d, e
];

Hierarchy (Child_ID, Parent_ID, Title, 'Parent')
LOAD 
Parent_ID,
Child_ID,
Parent_ID as Title
Resident Data;
```

Since you do not have a title, I used Parent_ID as the title.