# SQL Query with Optional Parameter and Possible Null Column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am having some difficulty returning all the results I would expect when leaving an optional sql parameter blank on a column that contain null values.

Imagine you have a table with the following (referredby is optional and can therefore be NULL):

```
Customertable
ID    CustomerName  ReferredBy
1      Aaron         Joe
2      Peter         NULL
3      Steven        Joe
```

Suppose I want to query with an optional SQL parameter for the referredby field like such:

```
declare @referredby as varchar(15)

select id, customername
from customertable<br>
where referredby = isnull(@referredby, referredby)
```

If I leave the parameter null, this would only return:
1 Aaron
3 Steven

How can I use an optional parameter to return all 3 results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This:

```
select id, customername
from customertable
where (referredby = @referredby OR @referredby is null)
```

For reasons [explained in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server), comparing `null = null` in sql server returns false (or unknown). As does `null != null`.

If you really like your syntax I believe you could make it work by setting ansi_Nulls to off: `set ansi_nulls off`

Comment: Ah, from what I had read, I thought that the syntax you used, and the isnull()... syntax were interchangeable

Comment: No, it's important to know that `IS NULL` and `ISNULL()` do very different things in SQL Server.  It can be confusing if you aren't familiar with the distinction between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line on your query:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... --other codes here
where (referredby = @referredby) OR (@referredby IS NULL)
```