# Why Ansi_nulls does not work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume that I have 2 tables named aTable1, aTable2

aTable1 has userID set to identity and contains the following data:

```
userID  email          FirstName    LastName
1       NULL               C            CC
2       NULL               D            DD
3       a@yahoo.com        A            AA
4       b@yahoo.com        B            BB
5       e@yahoo.com        E            EE
6       f@yahoo.com        NULL         NULL
7       g@yahoo.com        NULL         NULL
```

aTable2 contains the following data:

```
userID  email          FirstName    LastName    Title
3       a@yahoo.com      A            AA       student
4       b@yahoo.com      B            BB       student
5       e@yahoo.com      E            EE       student
NULL    NULL             C            CC       dean
NULL    NULL             D            DD       advisor
NULL    f@yahoo.com NULL    NULL               student2
NULL    g@yahoo.com NULL    NULL               student3
```

I want to update aTable2.userID based on aTable1, but knowing that 2 tables have null values in it, so i do like this:

```
set ANSI_NULLS off
update aTable2
set aTable2.userID = a.userID
from aTable a, aTable2 b 
where a.FirstName = b.FirstName and a.LastName = b.LastName and a.email = b.email
```

However, what this update does not update all the userID, in fact, it only updates those that have email not equal to null, but I already set ANSI_NULLS to off.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your update query to work, you can try something like this:

```
UPDATE a2
SET
   userId = a.UserId
FROM
    aTable2 a2
    JOIN aTable1 a ON 
        ISNULL(a.Email,'NULL') = ISNULL(a2.Email,'NULL') AND 
        ISNULL(a.FirstName,'NULL') = ISNULL(a2.FirstName,'NULL') AND
        ISNULL(a.LastName,'NULL') = ISNULL(a2.LastName,'NULL')
```

When the values are NULL, I've arbitrarily set the value to 'NULL' -- use some distinct value that will not appear in your data to ensure you won't receive false positives.

I've also seen other solutions using OR criteria in the JOIN and checking both values for NULL:

```
((a.Email = a2.Email) OR (a.Email IS NULL AND a2.Email IS NULL)) ...
```

Good luck.

Comment: @JackyNguyen -- np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 5):

It is documented that [it won't work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx):

> `SET ANSI_NULLS ON` affects a comparison only if one of the operands of the comparison is either a variable that is `NULL` or a literal `NULL`. If both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the setting does not affect the comparison.