# SQL not updating from join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im having an issue updating a table from a join. I did this kind of update many times but now its not working.
Here is the original query:

```
select 
surveydatakey
,a.Strata as [surveydata strata]
,SurveyPeriod
,DateOfSurvey
,StationLocation 
,a.CardType
,a.timeperiod
,station_entrance
,Direction
,DayType
,EntranceType
,b.Strata as ActuaStrata 
,StartDate
,currentdate
from surveydata a
inner join MAP_Entrance_Population b
on a.station_entrance_id = b.station_entrance_id
and a.timeperiod = b.tp
and  a.strata <> b.strata
where mode = 'train'
and a.strata not in (1,14,15,21,22,23)
and dateofsurvey between startdate and  currentdate
order by a.strata
```

Now this is the update query:

```
begin tran
update a
set a.strata = b.strata
from surveydata a
inner join MAP_Entrance_Population b
on a.station_entrance_id = b.station_entrance_id
and a.timeperiod = b.tp
and  a.strata <> b.strata
where mode = 'train'
and a.strata not in (1,14,15,21,22,23)
and dateofsurvey between startdate and currentdate
```

The search query produces 218 results, the update says that it changes 218 results.
In my search query I have the condition a.strata <> b.strata. My aim to to make these 2 equal each other. So I figured that after my update query, I should not get any results in my select query. But nothing actually changes. I still get the same 218 results after doing the update.

Any ideas?

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: Can you post an example of data?

Comment: I am using SQL Management Studio 2008

Comment: @veljasije The columns I am trying to update are just int.

Answer (score 0):

Could it because there isn't any records from Table B to be joined to Table A based on your join condition?

Try running the following query

```
select *
 from surveydata a
where mode = 'train'
and a.strata not in (1,14,15,21,22,23)
and dateofsurvey between startdate and currentdate 
and not exists
(
     SELECT 1
from MAP_Entrance_Population b
WHERE a.station_entrance_id = b.station_entrance_id
and a.timeperiod = b.tp
and  a.strata <> b.strata
 )
```

Comment: But they shouldn't I be getting no results from my select query? I am getting 218 results.

Comment: I noticed you have a BEGIN TRANSACTION in your statement. Just confirming whether you have committed this transaction?

Comment: In the query Im assuming that Im keeping the same ON clause as before. Im running it, but nothing is happening, it just keeps on running. (Its a very small dataset)

Comment: yes I have, but it should work anyway within the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following two queries

```
select 
.
.
.
from surveydata a
inner join MAP_Entrance_Population b
on a.station_entrance_id = b.station_entrance_id
and a.timeperiod = b.tp
where a.strata <> b.strata
and mode = 'train'
and a.strata not in (1,14,15,21,22,23)
and dateofsurvey between startdate and  currentdate
order by a.strata
```

*Update*

```
update a
set a.strata = b.strata
from surveydata a
inner join MAP_Entrance_Population b
on a.station_entrance_id = b.station_entrance_id
and a.timeperiod = b.tp
where a.strata <> b.strata
and mode = 'train'
and a.strata not in (1,14,15,21,22,23)
and dateofsurvey between startdate and currentdate
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe could happen if 218 records in `MAP_Entrance_Population` have `strata` set to `NULL`. In that case, your select query will bring rows back, as [`NULL` is not equal to `NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server) or anything else, and your update query will update `surveydata` to have `strata` set to `NULL`, which is *still* not equal to `NULL`.

When you find surprising things you can't quite figure out happening with the comparison operators in SQL, often the underlying cause is that you're comparing something with `NULL`.

Comment: I think you are right in terms of comparing to Null. I think I am doing that. Will need to look deeper into the query. Thank you