# Clojure: How do I delete an entry from a table when the rows are null? (in other words, containing no value)

Tags: sql, clojure

```
(sql/delete-rows "tableName" ["scenarioname = ? AND scenarioid= ?" nil nil]))
```

For some reason, this doesn't work... Why?

Comment: Try "is" instead of "="

Answer (score 2):

what you want is

```
(sql/delete-rows :tablename ["scenarioName is null and scenarioid is null"])
```

or

```
(sql/delete! dbcon :tableName ["scenarioName is null and scenarioid is null"])
```

assuming dbcon as your db connection.

Notes

- delete-rows is deprecated ->
  http://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc.deprecated/delete-rows
  use delete!
- null != null in SQL ->
  [Why does NULL = NULL evaluate to false in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server)
- clojure.java.jdbc where clause does not support operators like "is"
  "in" and "between"

Comment: Nvm. The error has to do with the work server I'm working on.