# sql and null values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, null

```
col1 col2
null null
aaaa null
bbbb null
```

col1=col2 - no rows returned

not (col1=col2) - following returned

```
aaaa null
bbbb null
```

Not (null) = null? so how is this being interpreted?

Comment: I think , Answer for this question is in:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1843460/4211782

Comment: Here is a good tutorial about `null` values: at http://www.guru99.com/null.html

Comment: I just ran your second query in SQL fiddle, and it returns no rows:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/22672.  My best guess is that `null` is not `null` but `'null'` -- the string, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing with `null` results in *unknown* which is `false`.

Use the `is` operator

```
where col1 = col2
or (col1 is null and col2 is null)
```

<sub>I added the `()` only for readabiliy. `and` has stronger operator precendence than `or`.</sub>

Comment: no, null = null is null. null = a is also null. both are false then.
I know the is operator, curious why null = null not returned.

Comment: Because NULL is not a known value. So if you have two unknowns you can't know if they are equal or not therefore they can't be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Please use isnull(col1,0)=isnull(col2,0)
because can't compare null with logical operations.

see below link:
[SQL is null and = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)