# Not Equal logic trouble in SQL Server

Tags: sql, logical-operators

I can't believe I'm having so much trouble with this.

Using this statement:

```
USE XXXX

SELECT 
    ID, DESCRIPTION, STATUS
FROM 
    PART
WHERE 
    PART.ID LIKE 'PCH%'
    AND PART.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%OBSOLETE%'
    AND PART.STATUS = 'O'
```

I get a table with 34 entries, each of them containing O in `PART.STATUS`.

What I actually want to say is, only show me the values which do NOT have a status of O. I know there are other ways around this. values that are not O should be null, but I'm annoyed that I can't figure out how the 'not equal' statement works. When I switch the last line to:

```
AND PART.STATUS <> 'O'
```

OR

```
AND PART.STATUS != 'O'
```

I get an empty table returned.

If I use the line

```
AND PART.STATUS IS NULL
```

I get the table I'm looking for.

What am I misunderstanding about the use of 'not equal statements'?

Comment: by using `is null` you got what you want?

Comment: You **cannot** use the normal equality (`=`) or inequality (`<>`) operators against `NULL` - using those against a `NULL` doesn't return a proper value - it returns `NULL`. In order  to check for `NULL`, you **have** to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` - there's no other way

Answer (score 3):

The problem is 3 valued predicate logic. When at least one side of predicate is `NULL` the result of predicate is `UNKNOWN`(no matter you use `=` or `<>` or `>` or `<`, ...), but `WHERE` clause only returns rows where predicate evaluates to `TRUE`. So our job is to make predicate to evaluate to `TRUE` when `PART.STATUS IS NULL`. This is done by adding additional check on `NULL` like:

```
USE XXXX
SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION,STATUS
FROM PART
WHERE 
PART.ID LIKE 'PCH%'
AND PART.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%OBSOLETE%'
AND (PART.STATUS <> 'O' OR PART.STATUS IS NULL)
```

Here is a little example. Imagine this is your table and you are issuing your statement `WHERE PART.STATUS <> 'O'`

```
PART(STATUS)
'A'
'O'
NULL
```

It evaluates to:

```
WHERE 'A' <> 'O' --TRUE
WHERE 'O' <> 'O' --FALSE
WHERE NULL <> 'O'--UNKNOWN
```

Since `WHERE` clause returns only rows where result of predicate is `TRUE`, you will get only 'A' here.

Comment: Right, even `null = null` is not `true` :)   The Wikipedia page for [SQL Null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)) is always helpful for a thorough discussion

Comment: @Andomar, yes there should be `at least one side of predicate is NULL`. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

the issue here is with the `null`value since every logical comparation against it would return false for example

```
PART.STATUS = NULL-- Would be false
PART.STATUS <> NULL-- would also return false
```

so you should do your comparison like

```
AND (PART.STATUS <> 'O' OR PART.STATUS IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

The part you're missing is that `NULL` is **not** a value, but the **absence** of it. A `NULL` means that the value in that field is either inexistent or unknown. That's why you cant' directly compare a value to a `NULL`. As stated in other answers, you have to use `PART.STATUS IS NULL`. Another option would be to use the `ISNULL` function, wich will test a value for `NULL` and, if it is, will return whatever value you specify on the second parameter. E.g.

```
USE XXXX
SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION,STATUS
FROM PART
WHERE 
PART.ID LIKE 'PCH%'
AND PART.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%OBSOLETE%'
AND ISNULL(PART.STATUS, '') <> 'O'
```

Check the documentation for [NULL in Sql Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504(v=sql.105).aspx) and the [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function. Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server) could be of use.

Comment: But you can directly compare `null` to a value. The result will be `unknown`. Not sure what you mean by "that field is either inexistent or unknown".  The `null` business is weird enough without introducing types of `null` :)

Comment: Well, as long as you can write `[some value] = null`, of course you can *compare* a value to a null... but the result will always be `unknown` as you state. Yeah, `null` is an entire logic on it's own, and I was only trying to rephrase what the documentation says. I think is one of those thinks that everybody can get in a general idea but will never really understand what it does under the hood.

Comment: When you read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)) you'll understand it (or at least, that worked for me.) The two gotchas are the existence of `unknown` on the same level as `true` or `false`. And that `null` is a value and `unknown` the result of an expression. `where null = 1` and `where unknown` are conceptually valid, but not `where null` or `where unknown = 1` do not.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE XXXX
SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION,STATUS
FROM PART
WHERE 
PART.ID LIKE 'PCH%'
AND PART.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%OBSOLETE%'
OR PART.STATUS != 'O'
```

Comment: Explain how this differs from the code posted in the question.  I had to read it four times before I saw it!

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson: in the question he used `AND PART.STATUS != 'O'`
while in my answer  i use `or`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your misunderstanding is probably about the NULL concept. NULL is not an empty string neither different from 'O', it's just [NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)).

That's why you have to use

```
AND PART.STATUS IS NULL
```

or

```
AND isnull(PART.STATUS, '') <> 'O'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to remember how NULL is treated in a database.  It isn't a value at all!

No operator (>,<,=.. etc) less (is) used will ever return rows with NULL.

writing in SQL  "where column = NULL" is like saying "give me all rows where the value isn't a value

Answer (score -1):

Null values can't be compared with equals(=)  or not equals operators. Try the below:

```
USE XXXX
SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION,STATUS FROM PART WHERE 
PART.ID LIKE 'PCH%'
AND PART.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%OBSOLETE%'
AND ISNULL(PART.STATUS, '') <> 'O'
```