# Unique constraint, but only if not null

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design, constraints, unique

Is it possible to make an unique constraint that only takes effect when a colum is not NULL?

Here's a example table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(
  col1 TEXT,
  col2 TEXT,
  col3 TEXT,
  UNIQUE(col1, col2, col3)
);
```

so if `col2` is NULL, I want it to be treated like `[col1, anything, col3]`

Comment: Use MS SQL Server, to "fix" the "problem" . See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server/21505140#21505140

Answer (score 3):

As the SQLite [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) explains, this is the default behavior for that and many other databases:

> If the `UNIQUE` keyword appears between `CREATE` and `INDEX` then duplicate
>   index entries are not allowed. Any attempt to insert a duplicate entry
>   will result in an error. For the purposes of unique indices, all NULL
>   values are considered to different from all other NULL values and are
>   thus unique. This is one of the two possible interpretations of the
>   SQL-92 standard (the language in the standard is ambiguous) and is the
>   interpretation followed by PostgreSQL, MySQL, Firebird, and Oracle.
>   Informix and Microsoft SQL Server follow the other interpretation of
>   the standard.

So, you can just create the index as you want to.

Comment: Interesting.  NULL values make the SQLite unique index non-unique.  It seems better from the point of view of the database analyst to require all unique indexes to be made up of NOT NULL fields.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc . . . If someone wants that, they can readily define the column with a `NOT NULL` constraint.  (Although I have an aesthetic appreciation that unique indexes should not have NULL values for the keys, there are times where it is handy.)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc null != null, nor should it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer for sqlite.  There are several DBMS products out there for which this is precisely the default.  If a UNIQUE constraint is defined, it still allows one or more entries with one or more of the columns in question to be NULL.

I'm not sure, but I think there are a few DBMS products out there that go the opposite way, sort of.  They won't allow an entry with a NULL value, unless uniqueness can be proven with the not null values.  The idea is that, when there are NULLS present, the answer to is_unique might be UNKNOWN.