# is null vs. equals null

Tags: sql, oracle, null, sql-update

I have a rough understanding of why `= null` in SQL and `is null` are not the same, from questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server).

But then, why is

```
update table 
set column = null
```

a valid SQL statement (at least in Oracle)?

From that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1844511/2986852), I know that `null` can be seen as somewhat "UNKNOWN" and therefore and sql-statement with `where column = null` "should" return all rows, because the value of `column` is no longer an an unknown value. I set it to `null` explicitly ;)

Where am I wrong/ do not understand?

So, if my question is maybe unclear:
Why is `= null` valid in the `set` clause, but not in the `where` clause of an SQL statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL doesn't have different graphical signs for assignment and equality operators like languages such as [c](/questions/tagged/c) or [java](/questions/tagged/java) have. In such languages, `=` is the **assignment operator**, while `==` is the **equality operator**. In SQL, `=` is used for both cases, and interpreted contextually.

In the `where` clause, `=` acts as the equality operator (similar to `==` in C). I.e., it checks if both operands are equal, and returns `true` if they are. As you mentioned, `null` is not a value - it's the lack of a value. Therefore, it cannot be equal to any other value.

In the `set` clause, `=` acts as the assignment operator (similar to `=` in C). I.e., it sets the left operand (a column name) with the value of the right operand. This is a perfectly legal statement - you are declaring that you do not know the value of a certain column.

Comment: all correct answers, but yours provides the most context. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

They completely different operators, even if you write them the same way.

- In a where clause, is a **comparsion operator**
- In a set, is an **assignment operator**

The assigment operator allosw to "clear" the data in the column and set it to the "null value" .

Answer (score 2):

In the set clause, you're assigning the value to an unknown, as defined by NULL. In the where clause, you're querying for an unknown. When you don't know what an unknown is, you can't expect any results for it.