# Why SQL does finally treat a NULL value as FALSE?

Tags: mysql, sql, null

Since `NULL` it's just an unknown or missing value, so maybe it's `TRUE` but we don't know. Why `FALSE` presumption? Does it have any justification besides "it's obvious" (since it is not) or should be considered a kind of SQL bad design artifact?

for ex.:

```
SELECT * FROM `rainbow_table` WHERE `show_me`
```

and some rows have null `show_me`. We really don't know if we should output such rows, maybe it is better to show it (as the last chance to prevent data loss)? It seems like SQL was developed by pessimists.

Comment: you may get some clarification regarding ur question here ... See below link : [http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/133600/should-i-store-false-as-null-in-a-boolean-database-field]

Comment: I think great answers and workarounds to your question are here http://stackoverflow.com/q/1843451/4155741 where can i find more of your duck test jokes?.

Comment: It doesn't treat `NULL` as false. This is trivially demonstrated by putting `NOT` in front of an expression and discovering that it's not treated as true.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name's tag edit has changed this from what I perceived to be a general/standard [tag:sql] (albeit one with some mysql syntax included) to being a more specific [tag:mysql] one. If it's your intention to ask specifically about mysql, let me know and I'll delete my answer. Otherwise, I'd suggest rolling back the tag edit and perhaps making clear that you want to discuss the SQL language rather than mysql specifically.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: mikhail is apparently using MySQL so I added the mysql tag just in case there are some gotchas in MySQL regarding nulls (or boolean values which MySQL doesn't have and simulates in a non-standard way). I think the combination of `sql` **and** `mysql` should indicate that SQL "only" answers are just as fine btw: your answer does not prove anything for MySQL as it doesn't support check constraints - but it _is_ a nice example where null means "not false" (rather than "true")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the context of a `SELECT` statement (so, in `ON` clauses, the `WHERE` clause, and within `CASE` expressions), predicates must be `TRUE` (not `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN`<sup>1</sup>) for the predicate to be satisfied.

However, within `CHECK` constraints, predicates must not be `FALSE` in order to be satisfied.

I.e. the following script will work:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
  ID int not null,
  Val varchar(10) null,
  constraint CK_Vals CHECK (Val in ('abc','def'))
);
INSERT INTO T(ID,Val) VALUES (10,NULL);
```

So we can see that it is not *universally* true in SQL that `UNKNOWN` results are treated as `FALSE`. It's also trivially demonstrated by the fact that wrapping a predicate that produces `UNKNOWN` with `NOT (<existing predicate>)` does not produce `TRUE`.

The wikipedia page on [Three-Valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) covers a lot of details.

---

<sup>1</sup>I'm assuming your question is about `UNKNOWN` rather than `NULL`, since you've tagged [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) and [relational-algebra](/questions/tagged/relational-algebra). In standard SQL, `UNKNOWN` and `NULL` are two distinctly different concepts. Only (so far as I'm aware) [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) conflates the two.

Answer (score 3):

SQL does not really treat `NULL` as false.  Instead, conditional statements are considered true only when the condition evaluates to true.

The effect is that `NULL` is treated as false.  But this does not mean that `NULL` is equivalent to false.

Comment: My question is exactly about why NULL is treated as false at the end. Therefore NULL is a kind of FALSE. We have one TRUE and two FALSEs. Duck test - "If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck."

Comment: but !NULL is not true.

Comment: @MikhailKarakulov . . . It is not that `NULL` is treated as false.  It is that `TRUE` is true and nothing else (to a close approximation).  In particular, `NULL` is not `TRUE`, so it fails all conditionals except `IS NULL` (and perhaps some extensions in particular languages).  Don't focus on `NULL`, focus on `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL NULL means it has some value but we don't know what is it. that's why when we compare we use like this

```
Select * from table [table name] where [column name] is not NULL
```

Comment: We cant write[ column name]<>NULL

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `Sql Server` engine is build upon three-valued predicate logic. If predicate compares 2 non null values then it can be evaluated to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If at least one of then is `NULL` then predicate evaluates to third logical value - `UNKNOWN`.

Now what happens in `WHERE` clause? It is designed in such a way that it returns rows where predicate evaluates to `TRUE` only! If predicate evaluates to `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN` then corresponding row is just filtered out from resultset.

At first this is very confusing and leads newcomers into world of `SQL` to several typical mistakes. They just don't think that data may contain `NULL`s. One of classic mistake is for example:

```
Employyes(Name varchar, Contry varchar) 
'John', 'USA'
'Peter', NULL
'Mike', 'England'
```

And you want all rows where `Contry` is not `USA`. And you just write:

```
select * from Employees where Country <> 'USA'
```

and get only:

```
'Mike', 'England'
```

as a result. This is very confusing at first glance, but as far as you understand that engine is doing three-valued logic the result is logical.