# SQL CASE query condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following condition in my stored procedure:

```
[DMO].[DriverModelName] =
   CASE WHEN ISNULL(@driverModelName,'NotSet') = 'NotSet' THEN 
[DMO].[DriverModelName]
   ELSE
@driverModelName
    END
```

This implies that when I pass `'NotSet'` to `varchar` parameter `@driverModelName`, it should return all the rows but for some reason it's returning only those rows which has a value in column `DriverModelName` & omitting the `null` value rows.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `NULL == NULL = FALSE`, *for the purpose of the `WHERE` clause*, unless you set `ANSI_NULLS` to `OFF`. Example:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

IF NULL = NULL
    PRINT 'TRUE'
ELSE
    PRINT 'FALSE'

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

IF NULL = NULL
    PRINT 'TRUE'
ELSE
    PRINT 'FALSE'
```

The result is:

```
TRUE
FALSE
```

In order to get all rows, including the `NULL` values, you should use

```
(@driverModelName IS NULL OR [DMO].[DriverModelName] = @driverModelName)
```

---

For references:

1. [http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2010/10/13/common-sql-server-mistakes-*1320*-equals-null/](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2010/10/13/common-sql-server-mistakes-_1320_-equals-null/)
2. [SQL is null and = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)
3. [Why does NULL = NULL evaluate to false in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server)

Additional Reading on Catch-All queries:

1. [Catch-all Queries](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)  by Gail Shaw
2. [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) by Erland Sommarskog

Answer (score 0):

Well if `[DMO].[DriverModelName]` is ever `NULL` what are you expecting the result of this `CASE` be?  Isn't this missing a `ISNULL()` around that column too?

```
ISNULL([DMO].[DriverModelName], 'NotSet') =
   CASE WHEN ISNULL(@driverModelName,'NotSet') = 'NotSet' THEN 
[DMO].[DriverModelName]
   ELSE
   @driverModelName
END
```

You cant say NULL = @someValue, it must be `IS NULL` or handle both sides with `ISNULL()`

Comment: Thanks @T McKeown & wewesthemenace. I tried both your suggestions however the procedure is still not returning rows where [DMO].[DriverModelName] is NULL. If the parameter  @driverModelName is null then I want to include all the rows weather DMO].[DriverModelName] has a value or is null or empty.

Comment: why don't you paste the entire where clause

Comment: @Felix Pamittan & McKeown, thanks a lot I got my solution from your posts.