# SQL Server Null Comparison between VARCHAR and CHAR

Tags: sql-server

**Problem:**

- I have a table with 2 columns , one char(1) and another varchar(1).
- I insert a row with NULLS
- I compare the 2 columns values
- I get that they are not equal
- Why?

**Code:**

```
CREATE TABLE ss_1
    (
      [char] CHAR(1) ,
      [varchar] VARCHAR(3)
    )



INSERT  INTO TimeCurrent..ss_1
        ( char, varchar )
VALUES  ( NULL,-- char - char(1)
          NULL  -- varchar - varchar(3)
          )

SELECT  CASE WHEN S.char = S.varchar THEN 'yes'
             ELSE 'no'
        END AS eq2
FROM    ss_1 AS S
```

**FIDDLE:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84bc4/2/0

Comment: NULL != NULL See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server

Comment: You could do this with 2 INTs and they are not equal too. UNKNOWN = UNKNOWN results in NOT EQUAL because it is unknown

Comment: @juergend, it is not because of unknown = unknown is not equal.

Comment: Oh got it, sorry for the silly question. Got confused with Javascript where null==null is TRUE

Comment: One solution: *SELECT  CASE WHEN **EXISTS(SELECT S.char INTERSECT SELECT S.varchar)** THEN 'yes'
             ELSE 'no'
        END AS eq2
FROM    ss_1 AS S*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is because `SQL` is based on three valued logic where a predicate can be evaluated to 3 different values: `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `UNKNOWN`. When any part of the comparison is `NULL` the predicate evaluates to `UNKNOWN`. This is the formal definition. Example:

```
1 = 1 => TRUE
1 = 2 => FALSE
1 = NULL => UNKNOWN
NULL = NULL => UNKNOWN
```

Now when you write:

```
CASE WHEN predicate THEN
```

It will go to `THEN` only when predicate evaluates to `TRUE`. But in your case it evaluates to `UNKNOWN`. Thats why it goes to `ELSE` part.

Comment: Got it, thanks..I should have googled a bit more before posting.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE ss_1
(
  [char] CHAR(1) ,
  [varchar] VARCHAR(3)
)



INSERT  INTO TimeCurrent..ss_1
    ( char, varchar )
VALUES  ( NULL,-- char - char(1)
      NULL  -- varchar - varchar(3)
      )

SELECT  CASE WHEN coalesce(S.char, '') = coalesce(S.varchar, '') THEN 'yes'
         ELSE 'no'
    END AS eq2
FROM    ss_1 AS S
```

Something like that might work for what you're after.  As was mentioned, a direct comparison of `null` against another `null` value will never return as equal, as `null` simply means the absence of a value, so there's no value for the comparison to compare against. The input types have no bearing on this (this would be the same if both were `char(1)` or char`(3)`, or some other data type for that matter).

EDIT: One thing to note, you'll want to replace the `''` with some other (otherwise not legal) value if blank is a valid input in your database for that column, else you'll end up matching blank values in the database against null values, which may or may not be okay...

EDIT 2: This actually might be slightly better, and more reflective of your actual intentions:

```
CREATE TABLE ss_1
(
  [char] CHAR(1) ,
  [varchar] VARCHAR(3)
)



INSERT  INTO TimeCurrent..ss_1
    ( char, varchar )
VALUES  ( NULL,-- char - char(1)
      NULL  -- varchar - varchar(3)
      )

SELECT  CASE WHEN S.char = S.varchar THEN 'yes'
        CASE When S.char IS NULL and S.varchar IS NULL Then 'yes'

         ELSE 'no'
    END AS eq2
FROM    ss_1 AS S
```

Comment: thanks, i was just testing for myself, i got around it using isnull(col,'') on both sides.. but like the other posters said, in SQL NULL is unknown, unlike Javascript