# Linq to SQL check for null strangeness

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq to SQL query that behaves (in my opinion) very strange when I check for null values.

There is a record in the DB as shown by the last Linq, but why does the 1st two queries not show the record?

```
//Check
(record.SomeID == null ? "Yes" : "No"); //This prints Yes

//LINQ
var q = (from t in mySQLTable
         where t.PKID == record.PKID && 
         t.SomeID == record.SomeID
         select t).FirstOrDefault();
 //This prints nothing.  I.e. no records found

var q2 = (from t in mySQLTable
          where t.PKID == record.PKID &&
          t.SomeID == (record.SomeID == null ? null : record.SomeID)
          select t).FirstOrDefault();
 //This also prints nothing.  I.e. no records found

 var q3 = (from t in mySQLTable
           where t.PKID == record.PKID &&
           t.SomeID == null
           select t).FirstOrDefault();
 //This prints 1 record
```

Comment: Simply "null = null" is always evaluate to false.

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk Are you sure ? Give it a try :)

Comment: Run profiler and compare result SQLs, i think you will understand what's going wrong

Comment: @user3185569 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server

Comment: I think the first one is generating a query like `SomeID = NULL` while the last is generating something like `SomeID IS NULL`

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk you should have written `null = null` because `==` made it look like a C# syntax.

Comment: Yes, my mistake :) I was talking about the behind query.

Comment: NULL is not a value. Null is a placeholder for the absence of a reference to an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overcome this issue using the below query:

```
bool isNull = record.SomeID == null;

var q = (from t in mySQLTable
         where t.PKID == record.PKID 
         && ( (isNull && t.SomeID == null)
             ||
              (!isNull && t.SomeID == record.SomeID)
            )
         select t).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Yes, that is working.  This however can become quite difficult to read (and lots of work) if there a number of ID's that you are checking.  Maybe an extension method might be the answer if this are used frequently.  Thanks.