# Why is `NOT(NULL=NULL)` false?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, logical-operators, three-valued-logic

`(NULL = 1)`  is **false**. Fine. Memorise as "NULL is defined not to be equal to any other value".

`(NULL = NULL)`  is **false**. Uhhh ... OK, fair enough . Memorise as "NULL represents an undefined value, so you never know whether it is or isn't equal to something else".

`NOT(NULL = NULL)`  is **false**. Wait, *What*!?

Seriously, how can that be valid? How can the behaviour of the "NOT()" operator depend on details of the expression that was being evaluated!?
Do all SQL systems do this?

---

Demo Query:

```
SELECT '"1 & 1"',
       '"1 = 1" is ' + (CASE WHEN (1=1) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS 'a=b',
       '"1 <> 1" is ' + (CASE WHEN (1<>1) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS 'a<>b',
       '"NOT(1=1)" is ' + (CASE WHEN NOT(1=1) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS 'NOT(a=b)',
       '"NOT(1<>1)" is ' + (CASE WHEN NOT(1<>1) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS 'NOT(a<>b)'
UNION
SELECT '"1 & 2"',
       '"1 = 2" is ' + (CASE WHEN (1=2) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END)AS 'a=b',
       '"1 <> 2" is ' + (CASE WHEN (1<>2) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END)AS 'a<>b',
       '"NOT(1=2)" is ' + (CASE WHEN NOT(1=2) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END)AS 'NOT(a=b)',
       '"NOT(1<>2)" is ' + (CASE WHEN NOT(1<>2) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS 'NOT(a<>b)'
UNION
SELECT '"NULL & 1"',
       '"NULL = 1" is ' + (CASE WHEN (NULL=1) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS 'a=b',
       '"NULL <> 1" is ' + (CASE WHEN (NULL<>1) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS 'a<>b',
       '"NOT(NULL=1)" is ' + (CASE WHEN NOT(NULL=1) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS 'NOT(a=b)',
       '"NOT(NULL<>1)" is ' + (CASE WHEN NOT(NULL<>1) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS 'NOT(a<>b)'
UNION
SELECT '"NULL & NULL"',
       '"NULL = NULL" is ' + (CASE WHEN (NULL=NULL) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END)AS 'a=b',
       '"NULL <> NULL" is ' + (CASE WHEN (NULL<>NULL) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END)AS 'a<>b',
       '"NOT(NULL=NULL)" is ' + (CASE WHEN NOT(NULL=NULL) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END)AS 'NOT(a=b)',
       '"NOT(NULL<>NULL)" is ' + (CASE WHEN NOT(NULL<>NULL) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS 'NOT(a<>b)'
```

Comment: Use the IS operator when comparing values to NULL

Comment: I'm well aware of that ... but that's not what this question is about.

Comment: why not ? `NULL` and comparison on `NULL` is __undefined__ . So SQL implementatons are free to implement whatever they want without any justification.

Comment: [Three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Application_in_SQL)

Comment: _(NULL = NULL) is false._? Says who?

Comment: @SalmanA #1 Have you run the Demo code? #2 Have you read the various answers?

Comment: Your demo code makes **wrong** assumptions. `CASE WHEN (NULL=NULL) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END` implies that `NULL = NULL` is definitely not true, **it does not mean that it is false**. Nowhere in the accepted answer it says that NULL = NULL is false.

Comment: @SalmanA Have you read the comments on the answers?

Comment: @Brondahl no. I didn't comment on those comments but on your question.

Comment: @SalmanA Fine. If you want to make snarky comments about how a question has false understanding in it (said misunderstanding being the specific cause of the question), rather than adding an answer that clarifies, or checking whether that clarification has already happened, then you're welcome to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [three-valued logic (3VL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Three-valued_logic_.283VL.29) defines the logical operators as:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| p       | q       | p OR q  | p AND q | p = q   |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| True    | Unknown | True    | Unknown | Unknown |
| False   | Unknown | Unknown | False   | Unknown |
| Unknown | True    | True    | Unknown | Unknown |
| Unknown | False   | Unknown | False   | Unknown |
| Unknown | Unknown | Unknown | Unknown | Unknown |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The *NOT* behavior has the following truth table:

```
+---------+---------+
| p       | NOT p   |
+---------+---------+
| True    | False   |
| False   | True    |
| Unknown | Unknown |
+---------+---------+
```

So, in the expression `NOT(NULL = NULL)`, you get:

```
NULL = NULL -> Unknown
NOT(Unknown) -> Unknown
```

Your case condition always acts like *not fulfilled* because your expression evaluates to Unknown, i.e. *neither true nor false*.

For more information on the way SQL Server works regarding nulls, have a look at [Why does NULL = NULL evaluate to false in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server)

Comment: Right ... yes, I see now ... My CASE queries haven't demonstrated "this value is true or false".... they've demonstrated that "this value is true **or not true**". I'm guessing if I put "IS NULL" checks in then my "Falses" would be shown to be "NULLs"?

Comment: nope, can't do that, because there really aren't bool values in SQL :(

Comment: Is it strictly accurate to say "You get `false` because SQL Server ..."? It feels more accurate to say  "You get `not true`, and if you look carefully you'll find that there's no SQL query that checks for 'Is this value `false`', they all check for 'Is the value `true`' ... thus `UNDEFINED` ends up appearing to act a lot like `false`".

Comment: e.g. my `CASE` doesn't test `true`/`false`, it tests "which case is `true`, or everything else". Similarly a `WHERE` clause does the same ... it ONLY tests "is this expression `true`"

Comment: rephrased my answer.

Comment: Cool. Minor nitpick ... you've switched between `unknown` and `undefined`. If those carry subtlely different meanings, could you clarify? If not could you standardise (just for benefit of future readers.)

Comment: @Brondahl: "SQL" (the query language) **does** have proper boolean values. But SQL Server (the DBMS product) does not support them.

Comment: @Brondahl - the distinctions are also important because a `CHECK` constraint must not be `false` in order to be satisfied - i.e. the rule is different for the expressions there than for `CASE` or `WHERE` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `NULL` is meant to represent the absence of a value or an unknown value. SQL is not consistent in choosing one of these meanings, but in most contexts `NULL` behaves like an unknown value.

`NULL = NULL` returns `NULL` because, if you compare two unknown values, the result is unknown. They could be identical or not.

There are ways to deal with `NULL`. The most common are `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` syntaxes. But you can also compare two values in a `NULL`-safe way. In this case, the syntax to use depends on the DBMS you are using. More details [here](https://federico-razzoli.com/null-comparisons-in-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite).

Comment: Hi @Federico, welcome to StackOverflow!
Everything you've said is correct, but I don't feel like it adds anything to the existing accepted answer - was there something specific that you were trying to add?

Comment: I think that a "theoretical" answer on *why* NULL=NULL is NULL was missing. And the link I added explains little known syntaxes for various databases. To be honest and avoid future accusations, the link points to my blog. Anyway, you judge if the answer is appropriate or not.