# C# string.Equals how to set the default StringComparison?

Tags: c#

Throughout our codebase we have 311 of the following cases:

```
string.Equals(stringA, stringB, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Using `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` accounts for like 99% of all `string.Equals` references.

I can't override either of these because `System.String` is a sealed class.

```
public static bool Equals(string a, string b)
public static bool Equals(string a, string b, StringComparison comparisonType)
```

Is the only option here to create a new static implementation like:

```
public static class StringComparer
{
  public static bool Equals(string a, string b)
  {
     return string.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
  }
}
```

Instead of writing the first code sample everywhere, is there a way to set CurrentCultureIgnoreCase as the default way of comparing strings ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you are asking how to change `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` then global search and replace is what I'd suggest.

Comment: @mjwills I think Zze means that rather than writing the first code sample _everywhere_, is there a way to set `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` as the default way of comparing strings.

Comment: @John that is correct. I have updated the question with your clarification.

Comment: No, that isn't possible. I'd suggest writing your own extension method called `EqualsIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an extension method (which does work with `null` arguments).

I named it `Eq` for brevity (but kept it `internal` so it doesn't confuse external consumers of your code)

```
internal static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>Performs a <see cref="StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase"><c>CurrentCultureIgnoreCase</c></see> equality check.</summary>
    public static Boolean Eq( this String x, String y )
    {
        return String.Equals( x, y, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase );
    } 
}
```

Used like so:

```
if( stringX.Eq( stringY ) ) {

}
```

Extension methods also work with `null` values without throwing a `NullReferenceException`:

```
String x = null;
String y = null;
if( x.Eq( y ) )
{
    // this will run without exceptions
}
```

---

For C# 8.0+ and latter with nullable-reference-types, you can improve the method with attributes, for example:

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

internal static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>Performs a <see cref="StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase"><c>CurrentCultureIgnoreCase</c></see> equality check.</summary>
    [returns: NotNullIfNotNull("x")]
    public static Boolean? Eq(
        this String? x,
        String? y
    )
    {
        if( x is null ) return null;
        return String.Equals( x, y, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase );
    } 
}
```

Or:

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

internal static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>Performs a <see cref="StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase"><c>CurrentCultureIgnoreCase</c></see> equality check. Always returns false when <param ref="x"/> is null.</summary>
    public static Boolean Eq(
        [NotNullWhen(true)] this String? x,
        [NotNullWhen(true)] String? y
    )
    {
        if( x is null ) return false;
        return String.Equals( x, y, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase );
    } 
}
```

That way the compiler can use this `Eq` method to also determine the `null`-state of `x` (assuming you're okay with `null.Eq( null ) == false`, [just like in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server)):

```
String? x = "foo" // or `null`;
String? y = "bar" // or `null`;
if( x.Eq( y ) )
{
    SomeMethodThatRequiresNonNullArgs( x ); // the compiler knows `x` and `y` are non-null here. 
}
```