# SQL Server NOT excludes null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in my table called `IsDuplicate`, nullable.

If I want to return all results where `IsDuplicate` is '0' or is null, I can do

```
WHERE ISNULL(IsDuplicate, 0) = 0
```

or I can do

```
WHERE IsDuplicate = '0' OR IsDuplicate IS NULL
```

However, this never works:

```
WHERE NOT(IsDuplicate = '1')
```

Why does this not work? This should cover both `IsDuplicate` equaling both '0' and NULL.

Comment: IsDuplicate - why would you ever have this as NULL? It's either a duplicate, or it's not, right? Seems like it should not be nullable. And why are you sometimes comparing your column to 0, sometimes '0', and sometimes '1'? If it's a bit, you should just be comparing it to 0 or 1, never the characters '0' or '1'.

Comment: `NOT(IsDuplicate = '1')` does not return true or false with a NULL value. The result is UNKNOWN.

Comment: Some reading here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null) and here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server) that goes some way to explaining.  Maybe it matters less to understand exactly "why", rather than just to remember what the rule is!

Comment: Its an interesting question, it would be easy to assume that it returns the records not returned by the condition inside, however the documentation says it "reverses the value of any Boolean expression." which still ignores nulls.

Comment: @mason this database is not my design. Every single value in our database is nullable.

Comment: "*Every single value in our database is nullable*" then better get used to using `IS [NOT] NULL`

Comment: WHERE IsDuplicate = '0' OR IsDuplicate IS NULL

Comment: `WHERE NOT(IsDuplicate = '1')` is just a different way of saying `WHERE IsDuplicate <> '1'`.  All that did was make the query appear confusing, which it apparently was given the question about NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Nulls aren't really a value. They are the absence value. You can see this in where clauses:

```
select * 
from foo 
where bar is null
```

instead of

```
select * 
from foo 
where bar = null
```

Bar could = 1, or it could be 34, or could have no value at all.

For example, I currently have 2 legs, 2 arms, and null tails. Is my tail a mouse tail? I don't have a tail to check against.

So for SQL, unless you specifically address the null they get ignored.

Comment: I would add “is my tail NOT a mouse tail?” Still don’t have a tail to check against.

Comment: I think its worth quoting from the documentation of "NOT" here to fully clarify e.g. "reverses the value of any Boolean expression." - because question is specifically about NOT, and it would be easy to assume that NOT will return the records not returned by the un-NOT-ed condition.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server the treatment of comparisons and boolean operators involving `NULL` values are influenced by the setting of `ANSI_NULLS` option. When this option is `ON`, and the `IsDuplicate` is `NULL` the result of both `IsDuplicate = '1'` and `NOT(IsDuplicate = '1')` is `UNKNOWN` (not `FALSE`).

For a row to be returned the `WHERE` condition should evaluate to `TRUE` (not `NULL` or `UNKNOWN`).

Check these:
Results of boolean operators involving `NULL`s and `UNKNOWN`s
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/null-and-unknown-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

and how `ANSI_NULLS` option works
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

And why `NOT` operator returns `UNKNOWN` from `UNKNOWN`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

In SQL,  when comparing values, the result can be **true** or **false** or **unknown**. i.e. a "3 way logic" applies.

So, for `NOT (some_value = 1)` if some_value is NULL, the result of the expression will be **unknown** instead of true or false, and this means that rows with NULL values will not be returned by this expression.

i.e. for "where NOT(unknown)"; the NOT cannot reverse **unknown** into true or false, so it remains **unknown** and is therefore excluded from the result.

refer: [The Three-Valued Logic of SQL](https://modern-sql.com/concept/three-valued-logic)